# Is there a way to re-write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}z^n$

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-product

> Is there a way to re-write
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}z^n$

I was thinking that I could use the cauchy product, but therefore I have to achieve this:$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{b_n}\right)$$ Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the question: rewriting the power series "in what way"? Do you actually want to find its radius of convergence?

Comment: Yes Jack, that's what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f(z)=\frac{-\ln(1-z)}{1-z}.$ By the Cauchy product we have

$$\begin{align*}
f(z) &= \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}\right )\left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\right )\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} \right )z^n\\ 
 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n z^n.\\ 
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, the interior sum can be expressed as the $n^\text{th}$ Harmonic Number $H_n$ which thus leaves us with

$$\sum_{n\geqslant1}H_n z^n$$

Or in other words: a generating function for the Harmonic Numbers. This, on the other hand, is a well-known one.

Consider the MacLaurin Expansions of $-\log(1-z)$ and $\frac1{1-z}$ multiplied as direct discrete convolution, i.e. as Cauchy-Product. Doing so we obtain

$$-\frac{\log(1-z)}{1-z}=\left(\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{z^n}n\right)\left(\sum_{n\geqslant0}z^n\right)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)z^n=\sum_{n\geqslant1}H_n z^n$$

> $$\therefore~\sum_{n\geqslant1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right)z^n~=~-\frac{\log(1-z)}{1-z}$$

Answer (score 1):

Interchange order (valid inside radius of convergence) and get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right) z^n
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1k\sum_{n=k}^\infty z^n
$$
which allows you to calculate the sum for sufficiently small $\lvert z\rvert$.

To find the radius of convergence, recall $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sim\log n$ and use Cauchy-Hadamard or similar.

Comment: Usually, I only observe one series when computing the radius of convergence - why are there two now?

Comment: The original series, together with the estimate $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sim\log n$, allows you to find the radius of convergence.  Then, as your original question asking for "re-writing", use the second double sum to calculate what it sums to.