# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}z^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}z^n$?

This notation really confuses me. Do I have to observe $a_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}$? And what method should I use then? I usually use Cauchy-Hadamard.

Comment: Defining $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}$, does that help simplify the cluster of double summations? Then apply Cauchy-Hadamard with $R^{-1} = \limsup_{n} H_n^{1/n}$.

Comment: Ratio test${}$?

Comment: ratio test works too, whats easier? I don't see how this would work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to re-write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}z^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273135/is-there-a-way-to-re-write-sum-n-1-infty-left-sum-k-1n-frac1k)

Comment: Of course, one could write for $z\ne 1$$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}z^n&=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac1k \sum_{n=k}^N z^n\\\\
&=\frac1{1-z}\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{z^{k}}k-\frac{z^{N+1}}{1-z}\sum_{k=1}^N \frac1k
\end{align}$$And now it becomes clearer as to the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly interpreted the notation.

You can use the ratio test to find the radius of convergence:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{n+1}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1 -\frac{1}{(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}} = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence is $1$.

$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)+\gamma+o(1)}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)},$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

This is equal to $1$ because $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\frac{\ln(\ln n)}{n}\right)=\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\ln n)}{n}\right)=\exp(0)=1,$$

using l'Hospital in the last step.