# A closed form expression of $\sum_{n \ge 0} \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \biggr)z^n$

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

> I am working on the following exercise: Use the identity $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n$ and elementary operations on power series (addition, multiplication, integration, differentiation) to find closed form expressions of the following power series:
>
> 1. $\sum_{n \ge 0} n^2z^n$
> 2. $\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{n}{n+1}z^n$
> 3. $\sum_{n \ge 0} \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \biggr)z^n.$

I have solved the first two points in the following way:

1. Using differentiation on the identity $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n$ we obtain

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} nz^{n-1}$$

and multiplying the above equality with $z$ yields $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} nz^{n}$ and again using differentiation and multplication with $z$ on this term yields $\frac{z^2+z}{(1-z)^3} = \sum_{n \ge 0} n^2z^n$ as desired.

2. Integrating the term $\frac{z}{(1-z)^2} = \sum_{n \ge 0} nz^{n}$ from before yields

$$\ln(\vert 1-z \rvert)+\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{n}{n+1}z^{n}$$

I realise that the third part is probably somehow related to the exercises before, but I do not see how. Could you please help me?

Comment: To clarify, in the third sum, since $n=0$ doesn't make sense in the inner sum $(1 \leq k \leq 0)$?, do you intend the outer sum to begin with $n=1$?

Comment: @SammyBlack [By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Formal_definition), $\sum_{1}^0a_k=0$, because it is the [empty sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum). So what they wrote is fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to re-write $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}z^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273135/is-there-a-way-to-re-write-sum-n-1-infty-left-sum-k-1n-frac1k)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding the sum: $$\sum_{n\ge 0}H(n)z^n=z+\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)z^2+\left(1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)z^3+...=\frac{z}{1-z}+\frac{1}{2}z^2+\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}\right)z^3+...=\frac{z}{1-z}+\frac{z^2}{2(1-z)}+...$$Where $H(n)$ is the $n$th harmonic number. Using induction, you could prove that: $$\sum_{n\ge 0}H(n)z^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{z^n}{n(1-z)}$$ Can you take it from here? (The series for $-\ln (1-z)$ is the sum of $z^n/n$ from $n$ to $\infty$, where $|z|<1$).

Note: I am assuming that the sums converge.

Answer (score 5):

Where these series converge,
\begin{align}
&\Bigl( \frac11 \Bigr) \, z 
+ \Bigl( \frac11 + \frac12 \Bigr) \, z^2 
+ \Bigl( \frac11 + \frac12 + \frac13 \Bigr) \, z^3 
+ \cdots \\
&\qquad = \frac11 \Bigl( z + z^2 + z^3 + \cdots \Bigr) 
+ \frac12 \Bigl( z^2 + z^3 + \cdots \Bigr) 
+ \frac13 \Bigl( z^3 + \cdots \Bigr) \\ 
&\qquad = \frac11 z \Bigl(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots \Bigr) 
+ \frac12 z^2 \Bigl(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots \Bigr) 
+ \frac13 z^3 \Bigl(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots \Bigr) \\ 
&\qquad = \Bigl( \frac11 z + \frac12 z^2 + \frac13 z^3 + \cdots \Bigr) 
\Bigl(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots \Bigr) \\
&\qquad = -\frac{\ln(1 - z)}{1-z}.
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't $\ln(1-z)$ an alternating series?

Comment: No, 
\begin{align}
\ln(1-z) &= -\int_0^z \frac{1}{1-t} \, dt \\ 
&= -\int_0^z \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n \, dt \\
&= -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^z t^n \, dt \\
&= -\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1} z^{n+1} \\ 
&= -\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m} z^m \\
&= -z - \frac12 z^2 - \frac13 z^3 - \cdots 
\end{align}

Comment: However, 
$$
\ln(1 + z) = z - \frac12 z^2 + \frac13 z^3 - \frac14 z^4 + \cdots
$$
which alternates.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarifying